# What to do if break wudu during Jumuah?

Tags: sharia, sunni, jumuah, shafii

What should I do if I break wudhu (e.g. by farting) during Jumuah?
I have a farting problem, I can hold it for some time but if the Quran recitation is long then there's a huge chance that someday I'll fart during some congregation prayer.
I don't think the 'only one wudu per prayer' applies to me because I can avoid farting for short prayers.
I ask this question as a preparation for the future.

> Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> Whoever cannot keep his wudoo’ for the duration of the prayer should
>   do wudoo’ and pray, and it does not matter what comes out of him
>   during the prayer, and his wudoo’ is not invalidated by that,
>   according to the consensus of the imams. The most he has to do is to
>   do wudoo’ for each prayer.
>
> Majmoo’ al-Fataawa, 21/221

-from [Does continually passing wind invalidate wudoo’? (IslamQA)](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/8910)

However, I feel that one day I might keep my wudu between two prayers (usually I fart after every salah) and this would cause me to fart (so I'd be responsible for farting). In this case, what should I do?

Basically, what does a Muslim do if he breaks his wudu during salah in congregation?

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, what does a Muslim do if he breaks his wudu during salah in congregation?

I assume you already heard a sound or smelled something as suggested by the link you posted in your question....

### So we have 2 cases here:

**-You are the Imam.**

**-You are praying behind someoneelse.**

---

In both cases, If you lose your wudu while praying then you **should** stop praying and leave the congregation to make wudu again.

For those praying behind a man it is easy. You can just leave or if you want to show some ettiqute you can do a trick to make those praying behind you fell that you are leaving because you lost your wudu and not because of them (i.e their mouth smell, they have gross feet). So what you so is, you can put your hands on your nose and remove it then look at it again as if you feel there is some blood coming down from your nose. I will leave it for you to come with a better solution..

As for the Imam, He has 2 choices:

1- Pull somone one from the 1st row and tell him to continue the prayer.

2- Without pulling anyone, He can assign any person in the 1st row to continue the prayer wothout that person changing his place.

---

**Sources:**

Happened with the Imam in my mosque.

Another Sheikh in another mosque gave us a lecture about Fiqh of leading the       prayers

Answer (score -3):

you have to break salah and re-make wudu. but if its a legitimate chronic problem(you'd have to do some research to see if you fall into that category and consult with a doctor) then your excused.