# Is prayer acceptable if my wudhu breaks?

Tags: salat, halal-haram, wudu

My *wudhu* breaks if I had gone to the toilet just before that, but if I wait for 20-30 minutes then it is not a problem.  Even in some case, it still breaks.  Will my prayer be accepted, if it breaks while praying?

Comment: Please put some more details in the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does dripping break Wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/does-dripping-break-wudu)

Comment: Maybe this hadith gives a hint http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/1

Answer (score 1):

Assalamuaikum.

I believe there's a another similar question posted.

[Breaking Wudu during Jumuah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/breaking-wudu-during-jumuah)

I will try to answer. If your wudu breaks while praying. The prayer is not considered. Instead, take wudu again and restart.

Sources :

http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=6188&CATE=147
http://islamqa.info/en/8910

Answer (score -1):

Salam,

Friend the answer you are looking for is on the following link. 
[Does wudu break - Similar question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/does-dripping-break-wudu)

In my opinion, if during namaz such a thing happens, if possible do not continue your namaz and perform wudu again and restart namaz. If not possible to break namaz like in Jumah, ask Allah for forgiveness. He is the Master of all and will inshallah forgive.

Original Answer:

> The general rule if you can control urination:
>
> > If you pass urine or drops of urine, you have to make wudoo’ and wash
> >     only the parts of the body and clothing (on which the urine has
> >     fallen).
>
> If you have no control over these drops:
>
> > If the situation you describe, the occasional emission of a few drops
> >     of urine, is beyond your control, then your case is like that of one
> >     who is incontinent, so do the following:
> >
> > 1. Wash the private parts with water.
> > 2. Wash the part of your clothes that
> >        the urine has gotten onto (there is no need to change your clothes).
> > 3. Put a pad or a piece of cotton, or something similar, over the private
> >        parts so that the urine will not spread.
> > 4. Do wudoo’ for each prayer, then pray as you are, and pray as much as
> >        you like, fard and naafil, with this wudoo’. After doing this,
> >        anything else that comes out does not matter. Allaah says
> >        (interpretation of the meaning): “So keep your duty to Allaah and fear
> >        Him as much as you can…” [al-Taghaabun 64:16]. Do not miss any prayers
> >        or delay doing them on time, and your prayer will be valid.
> >
> > This is what should be done in the case of incontinence, but if the
> >     urine comes out shortly after urinating, then it stops, in this case
> >     you can go to the bathroom fifteen minutes before the prayer or the
> >     adhaan, for example, then put something (a cloth, etc) to prevent
> >     contamination after you do istinjaa’ (cleaning yourself after
> >     relieving yourself), do wudoo’ and pray. And Allaah knows best.
>
> Fatwa by: [Al-Munajjid](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/6656/drops%20urine)

Comment: There are two problems with this post, which I don't consider to be an answer. 1). The real answer is not contained here but contains a pointer/link to an possible answer which would make this answer useless in case of [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot‎). 2). Answer are suppose to be objective, opinions are subjective.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Subjective answers can still be valid (but this one probably still needs work to meet that criteria); see "[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)"

Comment: Reg Point 1: @bleedingFingers: How many times have you not posted a link as an answer. Isnt there a possibilty that those links might "ROT" as well??
Point 2: Accepted.

Comment: @aMazing Irrespective of the fact whether userXYZ does it or not, an answer is supposed to be self-contained. And that rule applies to every answer including this one. So please [edit] the answer.

Comment: Appreciate the efforts that you are taking to run this community, however I would still stand by my point. 
If an existing answer could be used then why re-type the same.

Comment: Copy-paste answers are discouraged on this site.  See relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/324/22

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between the other answer by Newbie and my answer to this question?

Comment: It answer's the question while being self-contained and also mentions the source, although not totally upto the standard because it contains some irrelevant stuff. While this answer although contains an answer but the answer isn't tailored for this question, lacks effort and is a simple copy-paste from somewhere else which this site discourages. Please go through the [meta] discussion @goldPseudo has mentioned above.